# Unable to apt-get install probably because of iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, apt-get

I'm working with iptables on a OVH VPS but I can't access Ubuntu packages and I absolutely don't know why...

```
apt-get install package_name
```

says:

> package_name is not found

and auto-completion is unavailable.

But when I do an `apt-get update`, all the destinations are reached.

I paste my iptables list :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8443 state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:XXXX state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https state NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

If you see a missing rule, please tell me !

Comment: Most likely it has nothing to do with iprables. Instead edit your question and include the transcript of your commands (not a description of what you did)'

Comment: You are right ! It was a problem bash_completion and I solve it with http://askubuntu.com/a/191534